# How to pass argument function setState without MaterialPageRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the problem of updating the state. I need to pass a function with a `setState` into a widget, but I don't know-how. The issue is that I need to pass a static function and in there I can't do a `setState`. Which options do I have to fix it?

My code

```js
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NavigationBarState();
  }
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  bool showMusicTab = false;
  bool openMusicTab = false;
  int index = 4;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Home(),
    Search(),
    AddPost(),
    Notifications(),
    Profile(showMusicTabAndPlay)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: screens[index],
      persistentFooterButtons: showMusicTab
          ? <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 20,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white),
                  title: Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Break my soul',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: kRobotoBold,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.pause_circle_filled,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]
          : null,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: index == 0 ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
            ),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: index == 1 ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
            ),
            title: new Text('Search'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.add_circle,
              color: index == 2 ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
            ),
            title: new Text('Add post'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: index == 3 ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
            ),
            title: new Text('Notifications'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: index == 4 ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
              ),
              title: Text('Profile'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  static void showMusicTabAndPlay() {
    setState(() {
      showMusicTab = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: setState cannot be used inside a static function, why are you using it inside a static function in the first place??

Comment: @AhmedKhattab I know is what I try to ask, what I was asking, is how can pass a function with a `setState` to a widget, because when I pass the function without `static` is complaining to only pass static functions

Comment: You are creating the list of widgets as part of the field declaration, and at that point you can only use static values because instance values don't yet exist. You should instead populate `screens` during `initState`. (This unfortunately means you won't be able to make it `final` [yet].)

Comment: @Abion47 what do you mean by populate `screens`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you are trying to populate `screens` when the widget is first created by assigning it a `List` of objects directly at the field declaration:

```dart
class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Home(),
    Search(),
    AddPost(),
    Notifications(),
    Profile(showMusicTabAndPlay)
  ];

  ...
}
```

When you fill the object like this, you can only use static fields and methods to populate it. This is a problem for `showMusicTabAndPlay`, since it calls `setState` which is an instance method and cannot be called from a static method.

Instead, you should be populating `screens` within either the constructor or the `initState` method (with the latter being recommended):

```dart
class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  List<Widget> screens;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    screens = [
      Home(),
      Search(),
      AddPost(),
      Notifications(),
      Profile(showMusicTabAndPlay)
    ];
  }

  ...
}
```

With this, you can now have `showMusicTabAndPlay` be an instance method rather than a static method and the error will go away.